# Two instances on PHP CRUD in singleton

Tags: php, instance, crud

I'm using a CRUD class wrote in PHP using singleton pattern.
This is my CRUD file and my connection file.

https://pastebin.com/ZqSCnjqf - CONN

https://pastebin.com/301Maf59 - CRUD

The thing is: when I use the SELECT, which doesn't require a specific table selection, I can have how many selects I want. Like this:

```
$pdo        = Connection::getInstance();
$crud       = Crud::getInstance($pdo);
# ----------------------------------------
$sql        = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE prod_id = ?";
$arrayParam = array($prod_id);
$data_img   = $crud->getSQLGeneric($sql, $arrayParam, true);
```

But when I need to delete, insert or update I have to set the table on CRUD, like this delete:

```
$pdo        = Connection::getInstance();
$crud       = Crud::getInstance($pdo,'images');
# ----------------------------------------
$arrayImg   = array('img_id=' => $img_id);
$return     = $crud->delete($arrayImg);
```

I'm not being able to execute the two statements at once. Let's say I need to make an insert and a delete in same code block, it does run only one of them.

I'm stucked at this point where my code must find all images in DB with a product id, delete them on by one hile unlink the file on folder, and then, delete the product from table.

```
$prod_id    = $_GET['prod'];
# -----
$pdo        = Connection::getInstance();
# ----------------------------------------
$crud       = Crud::getInstance($pdo);
# -----
$sql        = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE prod_id = ?";
$arrayParam = array($prod_id);
$data_img   = $crud->getSQLGeneric($sql, $arrayParam, true);
# -----
foreach($data_img as $img_info)
{
  unlink('../../img/'.$img_info->img_name);
  $arrayImg = array('img_id=' => $img_info->img_id);
  $return2  = $crud->delete($arrayImg);
}
# ----------------------------------------
$crud       = Crud::getInstance($pdo,'products');
# -----
$arrayDel   = array('prod_id=' => $prod_id);
$return     = $crud->delete($arrayDel);
# ----------------------------------------
echo 'Deleted';
```

Is there any way to do that with that CRUD? Is a correct way to work with that?

Any help is welcome!

Thanks!

Comment: i can't understand why you need Singleton for `Crud` class, could you explain ?

Comment: It's not a need. It's just that I've been using this for a while and work fine.

Comment: Worked fine until now =) Now that I've found a limitation, I'm trying to find out if it's possible to improve it, or if it's a dead end. Pretty simple to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prupose you to modify your Singleton logic by this one.

```
class Crud
{
    private $pdo         = null; # Storing PDO connection
    private $table       = null; # Storing table name
    private static $crud = []; # Static attribute that contains a self instance

  # ----------------------------------------
    # Class constructor -> PUBLIC method
    # ----------------------------------------
    public function __construct($connection, $table = 'default')
    {
        if (!empty($connection)) {
            $this->pdo = $connection;
        } else {
            echo 'Conexão inexistente!';
            exit();
        }

        if (!empty($table) && $table !== 'default') {
            $this->table =$table;
        }
    }

    # ----------------------------------------
    # Static public method that returns a Crud class instance
    # ----------------------------------------
    public static function getInstance($connection, $table = 'default')
    {
        # Verifying if there's a class instance
        if (!isset(self::$crud[$table])) {
            try {
                self::$crud[$table] = new Crud($connection, $table);
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                echo 'Error '.$e->getMessage();
            }
        }
        return self::$crud[$table];
    }
}
```

i have transform your private static property `$crud` as array, and store each instance isolate by table name.

Important change is highlight here :

```
        if (!isset(self::$crud[$table])) {
            try {
                self::$crud[$table] = new Crud($connection, $table);
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                echo 'Error '.$e->getMessage();
            }
        }
```

So following code will work like this :

```
Crud::getInstance($pdo); // Create new instance and store it on key 'default'
Crud::getInstance($pdo); // Just return 'default' instance

Crud::getInstance($pdo,'foo'); // Create new instance and store it on key 'foo'
Crud::getInstance($pdo,'foo'); // Just return 'foo' instance
```

Comment: It worked very well. Thank you very much! Do you think it might be a good idea to create a config file already setting all the cruds/tables that I will be using on my application?

Answer (score 0):

The `Crud` class that you use allow only one instance to be stored in it. No modifications after that. This is done from this part of the code:

```
public static function getInstance($connection, $table=null)
  {
    # Verifying if there's a class instance
   if (!isset(self::$crud))
    {
      try
      {
        self::$crud = new Crud($connection, $table);
      }
      catch (Exception $e)
      {
        echo 'Error '.$e->getMessage();
      }
    }
    return self::$crud;
  }
```

The first time you call getInstance it sets the instance inside the static class, and all subsequent calls after it returns the instance already set from the first call. No matter if you give different connections or tables at all.

In this case you will have to use new instances of Crud for different tables/connections. Don't use 'getInstance' but instead create a new instance with `new Crud(...)`.